# More cleaner way of selecting elements in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Currently i'm look at scraping some links from a table on coinmarket, the code looks fine except it looks a bit hardcoded. What i wanted to find out is there a better way to condense an XPath or by using a selector. Currently what i've coded is

```
def get_all_links(self):
        """
        Return a list of links from the webpage
        

        """

        prop_container = self.driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[4]/table')
        table_body_container = prop_container.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='./tbody')
        table_row_list = table_body_container.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='./tr')
        
        link_list = []

        for crypto in table_row_list:
            a_tag = crypto.find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME, value='a')
            link = a_tag.get_attribute('href')
            link_list.append(link)
        

        return link_list
```

It does return the information correctly i.e 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/sei', my problem is that first find_element, its practically a full xpath copied over. Is there a way to reduce this? The table has a class also attached to it 'Table class="sc-66133f36-3 etbEmy cmc-table' prehaps i can use this in some sort of way

Comment: I'm not sure but `coinmarket` may have  `API` to get data without scraping.

Comment: in xpath you can use other values: `id`, `class`, `data-item`, `placeholder`, text in table, etc. You have to find unique value to search object in HTML. You can search unique values even in parent element.

Comment: documentation for [Coinmarketcap API](https://pro.coinmarketcap.com/api/v1)

Comment: you can try `//table[@class="sc-66133f36-3 etbEmy cmc-table"]` but I don't remember if `Selenium` doesn't have problem with multi-classes (when string has spaces) and it may need to use `CSS` selector `By.CSS` with dots instead spaces `table.sc-66133f36-3.etbEmy.cmc-table`. Or `xpath` with `contains()` like `//table[contains(@class, "sc-66133f36-3 etbEmy cmc-table")]`

Answer (score 0):

Your selector can be simplified.

Table is placed in section with unique id `section-coin-markets` and all href inside the table have class `cmc-link`, so css selector for all hrefs in the table is:

```
#section-coin-markets a.cmc-link
```

Same in xpath (css declaration is shorter, so I prefer css):

```
//*[@id='section-coin-markets']//a[contains(@class, 'cmc-link')]
```

If you need to get content per `tr` in table, tr locator should be smth like

```
#section-coin-markets tbody tr
```

```py
table_row_list = table_body_container.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#section-coin-markets tbody tr')
        
link_list = []

for crypto in table_row_list:
   a_tag = crypto.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.cmc-link')
   link = a_tag.get_attribute('href')
```